# What is the purpose of this code, I dont get it

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

What is this code doing? any help please, I am new to python, can someone explain me what is gray[:,0] doing? I dont undestand this part " [:,0] "

```
while np.sum(gray[0]) == 0:
      gray = gray[1:]

  while np.sum(gray[:,0]) == 0:
      gray = np.delete(gray,0,1)

  while np.sum(gray[-1]) == 0:
      gray = gray[:-1]

  while np.sum(gray[:,-1]) == 0:
      gray = np.delete(gray,-1,1)

  rows,cols = gray.shape
```

Comment: What part specifically do you need help with understanding?

Comment: your question isnt specific. Plus i dont see why you would be using multiple whiles like that for conditional statements when if and elif would make more sense

Comment: I got this code from a tutorial, I don't understand this part "gray[:,0]". What is [:, 0]

Comment: [This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) would be a good relevant page to read over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is selecting specific elements out of the numpy array.

The colon is used to specify a range, and if the first number isn't specified it starts at 0, and if the last number isn't specified it goes to the end.

The comma is used to separate dimensions.

[:, 0] selects the item in column 0 of every row.

Simple example:

`array = np.array([[0,1],[2,3]])`

Output:

`array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])`

---

`array[:,0]`

Output:

`array([0, 2])`